# init: airflow-webserver respawning too fast, stopped

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, airflow

I am not able to run upstart script in ubuntu 14.04

```
description "Airflow webserver daemon"

start on started networking
stop on (deconfiguring-networking or runlevel [016])

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setuid airflow
setgid airflow

env AIRFLOW_CONFIG=/home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow.cfg
env AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ubuntu/airflow

export AIRFLOW_CONFIG
export AIRFLOW_HOME

exec usr/local/bin/airflow webserver
```

When I run this file, i get following error in var/log/syslog

```
Feb 23 22:53:52 ip-10-200-10-81 kernel: [ 3984.957766] init: airflow-webserver main process ended, respawning
Feb 23 22:53:52 ip-10-200-10-81 kernel: [ 3984.961133] init: airflow-webserver respawning too fast, stopped
```

And I run

```
sudo initctl airflow-webserver status
```

I get following error

```
initctl: invalid command: airflow-webserver
Try `initctl --help' for more information.
```

what I am doing wrong ? What should I do ?

Comment: Shouldn't ```usr/local/bin/airflow webserver``` be ```/usr/local/bin/airflow webserver```?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: I used ubuntu 16, and make sure you create airflow user on machine